# "Reverse Groups" challenge

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge, io, comparative-review, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to do the [Reverse Groups Challenge](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/71/) on [CodeEval](http://codeeval.com):

> Given a list of numbers and a positive integer k, reverse the elements of the list, k items at a time. If the number of elements is not a multiple of k, then the remaining items in the end should be left as is.

My logic is functional, but when I try to submit my solution is says that it timed out at 10 seconds. How can I improve the speed here?

```
File.open(ARGV.first).readlines.each do |line|  
  values, k = line.split(';')
  k = k.to_i
  values = values.split(',')
  current = values.shift(k)
  str = ""   
  while current.count % k == 0 do
    current.reverse_each{ |val| str += "#{val},"}
    current = values.shift(k)
  end    
  str << "#{current.join(',')}"
  puts str
end
```

Other attempt:

```
open(ARGV[0]).readlines.each do |line|  
  values, k = line.chomp.split(';')
  k = k.to_i
  values = values.split(',')
  current = values.shift(k)
  str = ""   
  while current.count % k == 0 do
    current.reverse_each{ |val| str << "#{val},"}
    current = values.shift(k)
  end    
  str << "#{current.join(',')}"
  puts str
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say what CodeEval's time limits are, or why this code should *particularly* slow. There are a lot of things you could do differently, though:

1. Instead of `readlines`, you can use `each_line` to iterate the lines, instead of reading all of them into an array, and then iterating.
2. You can get the values and `k` in a single line:

   ```
   *values, k = line.chomp.split(/[,;]/)
   ```
3. Look up `each_slice`; it'll iterate an array in "chunks" of the given length
4. Don't do "manual" string concatenation. You already use `join` in one place, but you can use it anywhere you need a string representation of an array.
5. You're shifting `k` items off of the array, and you then check if the number of shifted items is divisible by `k`. But `shift` will either shift exactly `k` items or fewer, so the modulus operator is a really roundabout way of saying `current.count == k`.
6. You code fails if there are blank lines. CodeEval doesn't say whether the file can contain blank lines, but, if it does, well...

All in all, you're approaching this very procedurally. A nicer approach would be something like

1. Chunk the items in `k`-sized arrays (the last chunk may be smaller)
2. Reverse the chunks that are `k` items long
3. Put the arrays back together into one
4. Join with commas and print

Or, in code:

```
File.open(ARGV.first).each_line do |line|
  *items, k = line.chomp.split(/[,;]/)
  next unless k # skip empty lines
  puts items.each_slice(k.to_i).map { |group| group.count < k.to_i ? group : group.reverse }.flatten.join(",")
end
```

*Edit: As Naklion points out in the comments, using `flat_map` is of course better than using `map` and `flatten` separately, i.e.:*

```
items.each_slice(k.to_i).flat_map { |group| group.count < k.to_i ? group : group.reverse }.join(",")
```

*I've update the rest of the code blocks to use `flat_map`*

That 3rd line is a bit long, though, so to spell it out:

```
File.open(ARGV.first).each_line do |line|
  *items, k = line.chomp.split(/[,;]/)
  next unless k
  chunks = items.each_slice(k.to_i)
  reversed = chunks.flat_map { |chunk| chunk.count < k.to_i ? chunk : chunk.reverse }
  puts reversed.join(",")
end
```

You can also do pop off the last chunk if you know it to be smaller than `k`, which lets you say simply `map(&:reverse)` on the remaining elements

```
File.open(ARGV.first).each_line do |line|
  *items, k = line.chomp.split(/[,;]/)
  next unless k
  k = k.to_i
  chunks = items.each_slice(k).to_a
  tail = items.count % k == 0 ? [] : chunks.pop
  puts chunks.flat_map(&:reverse).concat(tail).join(",")
end
```

Last alternative: Pop off enough items that the remaining ones are cleanly divisible by `k` before slicing

```
File.open(ARGV.first).each_line do |line|
  *items, k = line.chomp.split(/[,;]/)
  next unless k
  k = k.to_i
  tail = items.pop(items.count % k)
  puts items.each_slice(k).flat_map(&:reverse).concat(tail).join(",")
end
```

But frankly, I like the first code block the best.

All of these are a little faster than your code, by the way. It's not a huge difference, but it's faster.

Comment: Thanks very detailed and understandable. You provide a lot of helpful info.

Comment: Sorry, can't check right now, but it seems, you don't need `.chomp`

Comment: And what about `flat_map`?

Comment: @Nakilon True, `chomp` probably isn't needed. The newline will be there, but will get removed by `to_i`. And, yes, `flat_map` - I always forget about `flat_map` for some reason. Thanks

Comment: @Nakilon Just checked, and without `chomp`, `k` becomes `"\n"` for blank lines, so the `next unless k` line won't work as intended. So might as well use `chomp`, I figure

Comment: @Nakilon flat map increases speed from 129 ms to 92 ms!

Comment: Antarr, I assume the speed increase you cite is for #1 with `flat_map`. Correct? Did you time either of the chunky methods? I've found `chunk` tends to be rather slow, but that may just be for the limited tests I've done in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably exceeding the time limit because you have an infinite loop.  If the length of the list is a multiple of *k*, then at some point `values` and `current` will both be empty arrays.